# C# SoundPlayer not working properly when put after Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#, .net, console, soundplayer

I have a very simple console application where I'm trying to play a wav file with SoundPlayer.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer("path/to/sound.wav");

    while(true){
        Console.ReadLine();
        sp.PlaySync();
    }
}
```

It works fine except when `PlaySync()` is right after `Console.ReadLine()`. It seems the longer I wait before putting an input, the lower the volume of the sound.

I have tried using `sp.Play()` (the asynchronous version) and I have tried putting a `Thread.Sleep()` delay between them. There was no difference. What could be the cause of this?

(This is my first post here so forgive my mistakes)

Comment: "I have tried using sp.Play() (the asynchronous version) and I have tried putting a Thread.Sleep() delay between them." What happened when you tried each of them?

Comment: Ah, sorry I wasn't clear. The changes didn't work.

Comment: You should never say "didn't work" when describing a problem, because it is simply too vague. Did it behave the same as before? Did it not work in some other new way?

Comment: I suggest you wait for the sound file to be loaded first, before playing it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. There was no noticeable difference. So I've ruled out blocking the main thread as an issue. The wav file is 2 seconds long

Comment: The solution was using sp.Stop(). You led me the right way, thanks.

Comment: You can post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as simple as the question. Use `Stop()` every time `PlaySync()` is called.